# How to open a .jar file by default on windows 10 64 bit

Tags: java, windows, java-8

I have a jar file. I'm using windows 10, 64 bit. This jar I'm trying to open was opening with the 32 bit version of java. The default program was 

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre.1.8.0_221\bin\jawaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*` 
located in "Program Files (x86)" so I deleted that Java folder. Now when I try to open my jar with the command

`java -jar decoder_new.jar`

it's opening correctly using the 64 bit version of java. But when I try to double click the jar, a blank terminal briefly opens, then closes, and nothing happens. I tried selected a program to open it, but I don't know which program to use. I have two folders in `C:\Program Files\Java` namely `jdk1.8.0_111` and `jre1.8.0_111` and within `jre1.8.0_111` there is only `lib`. How can I set a default program to open my jar using the 64 bit version of java?

Comment: If your JRE only has a `lib` directory, it is a corrupted installation.  Uninstall it if possible, then reinstall it.  If that’s not possible, delete it manually and reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

quoting [How to open a jar file page](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001343.htm)

Once you have your jre installed and running on wiirndows

> 1. Right-click the file and select Open With.
> 2. In the Open With window, click the Browse button to open the File Explorer window.
> 3. You need to find the Java executable file (java.exe file) on your computer hard drive. It is often located in the "Program Files\Java" or "Program Files (x86)\Java" folder, within a possible subfolder below the Java folder. Once you find the file, select it and click OK.

If the jar file is executable it will run, otherwise it will open like a zip folder.

Comment: I can't find the `java.exe` file in the `jre` folder, but under the `bin` folder in the `jdk`, it's there. But when I click it, it's doing the same thing, a blank command prompt flashes, and nothing happens.